# How to resolve multiple querysets in graphene.Union?

Tags: python-3.x, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I want to create a graphene.Union type of multiple existing types. I am able to resolve it but it is not in my required format.

## Schema

```py
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

class ageType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = age

class ethnicityType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ethnicity

class combinedType(graphene.Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (ageType, ethnicityType)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    defaultPicker = graphene.List(combinedType)
    def resolve_defaultPicker(self, info):
        items = []
        age_q = age.objects.all()
        items.extend(age_q)
        ethnicity_q = ethnicity.objects.all()
        items.extend(ethnicity_q)
        return items
```

The query I am using in the graphql admin:

```py
{
  defaultPicker{
    ... on ageType{
      id
      age
    }
    ... on ethnicityType{
      id
      ethnicity
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get a output like this:

```py
{
  "data": {
    "defaultPicker": [
      'ageType': [{
        "id": "2",
        "ethnicity": "American",
        "ethnicityFr": "Test"
      }],
      'ethnicityType': [{
        "id": "1",
        "familyPlans": "3 kids",
        "familyPlansFr": "3 enfants"
      }],
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried many things but couldn't find a way to resolve it.

Comment: I don't think this is how uniontype should be used. What's wrong with just defining connection/list type for ageType and ethnicityType? Also, in this case, what's the advantage of using union type?

Comment: @JechChua Yeah, using list type made it work!

Comment: Nice! I'm glad it worked out